# Different behaviour when an application is called by a service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, service

When executing an application as a user account (with admin privileges), everything works as it is supposed to.

However, when calling a service which executes the same application, but from the `SYSTEM` account, the application runs as it is supposed to, however it does not find any ODBC or printer drivers. To allow the service to call the application, I am using [the following code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite?fid=1539607&fr=31#xx0xx).

I would imagine that the SYSTEM account has full privileges and can do anything which the administrator user account can do. The only thing I can think of is something going on in the linked code, when switching the session from 0 to 1, so that the application can appear in the user's desktop.

What could the problem be?

This is my service's code, which calls the `ApplicationLoader` class which is shown in the above link (codeproject.com).

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC("C:\\", "\"C:\\MyApp.exe\"", out procInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ODBC and printers are configured per-user. And since you can't login as SYSTEM, you'll have to add those connections through code or just not use the SYSTEM account, perhaps a dedicated user account for only that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - looks like I need a different approach.